# I Have Bind the Image To the gridview From Folder, But after running the application it is not displaying the image?

Tags: asp.net

I am struggling with this below code.

I have tried to display it in grid view but I am unable to do that . please help me to get out of this...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] ImagePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\ITS-Software_1\\Downloads\\Emojis");
            List<ListItem> Imgs = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string imgPath in ImagePaths)
            {
                string ImgName = Path.GetFileName(imgPath);
                Imgs.Add(new ListItem(ImgName, "~/Images/" + ImgName));
            }
            Gv_imgs.DataSource = Imgs;
            Gv_imgs.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

//this is the HTML code of the gridview. I have tried by doing some changes in this also but it is not helpful.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="DisplayImageInGridView.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    File:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fupload" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CssClass="button" 
                        Text="Upload Selected File" onclick="btnUpload_Click"
                        />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:GridView ID="Gv_imgs" CssClass="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowHeader="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" ControlStyle-Height="75" ControlStyle-Width="75"
                    HeaderText="Images" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your GridView html

Comment: You have an empty catch block. Start by handling the exception . If there is an error (probably path related) you will never find out. And start using `Server.MapPath`.